# How to create SSL certificate & implement in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, openssl, ssl-certificate

Following spring security book, I try to create SSL certificate through the following commands but getting an error which I mention in the last. grateful for the help. I've tried openssl as well as with wimpty:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out certificate.p12
-name "certificate"
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8088
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certificate.p12
server.ssl.key-password=12345
```

Also, I've placed certificate.p12 under resources folder.

But all efforts ending up on the following error:

```
2021-11-21 23:49:20.738  INFO 16764 --- [           main] com.kash.SpringsecurityApplication       
: Starting SpringsecurityApplication using Java 11.0.12 on LAPTOP-BQ48GM36 with PID 16764 
(B:\spring\springsecurity\target\classes started by The Kash in B:\spring\springsecurity)
2021-11-21 23:49:20.742  INFO 16764 --- [           main] com.kash.SpringsecurityApplication       
: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-21 23:49:22.272  WARN 16764 --- [           main] 
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization 
- cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable 
to start web server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 
'classpath:certificate.p12'
2021-11-21 23:49:22.280  INFO 16764 --- [           main] 
ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application 
with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-21 23:49:22.299 ERROR 16764 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               
: Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested 
exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 
'classpath:certificate.p12'
at g.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
 ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) 
~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.springframework.context.
 support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring- 
 context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~ 
[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring- 
boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~ 
[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot- 
 2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot- 
 2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot- 
2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at com.kash.SpringsecurityApplication.main(SpringsecurityApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
 Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 
 'classpath:certificate.p12'
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat
 .SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:132) ~[spring-boot- 
 2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.S
 at slConnectorCustomizer.configureSsl(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:92) ~[spring-boot- 
 2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded
   .tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:129) ~ 
  [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What is `wimpty`? What is your book you are reading?

Answer (score 0):

I remove the project & re-create it. & use the following command that works:

keytool -genkey -alias  -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore

it also recommended to migrate jks to pkcs512

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.jks -destkeystore certificate.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12

Be sure that generated .p12 file should be placed under resources folder.